# Include run-time args in gradle executable jar file

Tags: java, gradle, jar, executable, init.d

After much searching, during which I've found how to include run-time args in my build.gradle file for running an executable jar *from* *gradle*, and even how to include JVM arguments, I have failed to locate the answer to this question:

I have an app "myapp.jar" that takes an argument "--demo-mode".  I'm using gradle application distTar and distZip plugins to make this into an executable jar with its own script (so I can run it directly as "./myapp.jar").

I need to add this jar to /etc/init.d, which I have done by simply symlinking the jar file into the init.d directory (and running update-rc.d).

Now, the app runs just fine without the --demo-mode argument when I boot the system, just as I want (when not using demo mode, that is).

I can also go into the app-owner's home directory, set RUN_ARGS="--demo-mode" and run "./myapp.jar" and it will launch in demo mode.  Cool.  (peeking inside the jar at the default gradle-generated build script shows that $RUN_ARGS is included after the jar file name in the command that actually executes the jar)

What I can't seem to do is have /etc/init.d launch the jar file *using the built-in Gradle launch script* and with the --demo-mode argument applied.

I know I can write my own launch script for /etc/init.d and include the arg "manually" (something like "su - user -c "java -jar /home/user/myapp.jar --demo-mode")

I could also deconstruct the jar file and manually hack the launch script...

I even tried exporting RUN_ARGS in the jar-owner's .bashrc, hoping it would get picked up when the script ran... (no joy)

But is there a way to configure Gradle (or use some other method) so that the included launch script also includes the command-line argument(s) that I want to pass to my jar?

Comment: Which version of Gradle are you using, or does it matter?

Comment: version 2.14, and I have no idea whether it matters :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the application plugin tasks, installDist, distZip or distTar, will create startup scripts, {install or distributions archive}/bin/.

These are OS specific shell scrpts which start the application at last. You could append your arguments.

```
...
exec "\$JAVACMD" "\${JVM_OPTS[@]}" -classpath "\$CLASSPATH" ${mainClassName} "\$@"
```

Notice the script would pass all its argument to the underlying ${mainClassName}.